# How to delete a module from the Modules menu?

Tags: installation

I have installed a few modules that I don't use at all. I can't find any option to uninstall them. How do I do it? Is there a separate module to do it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure about a separate module for this, but you can just delete the module folder in your `sites/all/modules` folder. Works for me every time.

Comment: Don't do that while the module is enabled though, or you _will_ be sorry some day.

Comment: This is wrong, it shouldn't be the accepted answer. Someone following this advice could get into serious trouble if they don't disable and uninstall the module first.

Answer (score 3):

The module uninstall page in Drupal 6 is at http://mysite.com/admin/build/modules/uninstall.

For Drupal 7 it's at http://mysite.com/admin/modules/uninstall.

Once you disable a module using the main modules page, visit the uninstall page and you'll be able to safely uninstall. After that it's just a matter of deleting the module folder from your server, and you won't see it in the module list any more.

Whatever you do, don't just delete the module folder without disabling/uninstalling it first, or you could easily wreck the site.

Comment: But each and every module isn't always listed in the uninstall page in D7. What then?

Comment: @Ali Then...nothing :) In my experience every module that gets installed is available to be uninstalled in Drupal 7. But if one isn't, I'd imagine Drupal is just being clever and realising that the particular module doesn't implement `hook_uninstall()` or `hook_disable()`, and so running the uninstall procedure would be futile. Hence it's not displayed in the list

Comment: But my experience says otherwise (although I'm not experienced enough :-)). So technically in that case after disabling it, it can be safe to delete the folder manually?

Comment: @Ali Absolutely, yes :)

Comment: Hmm. Very good advice. I should be more careful from now on...

Comment: @Ali, to clarify the "wreck the site" statement.  When you don't properly uninstall a module, you don't give the module a chance to clean up after itself.  This means that variables get left in {variable}, you may have extra tables in the database, extra columns in the database, orphaned files, etc.  Things can get really messed up.

Comment: Wow I never actually thought of that! Thanks for another great advice!

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you're using a drupal version prior to 7.

In this case you can deactivate them in the module list and then just delete them via FTP.

In Drupal7 there's an uninstall tab in the module list...

Comment: There's also an uninstall tab in Drupal 6